# How do I create a for loop per customer to find the aggregated weightage of each campaign?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, aggregate

I have the following DataFrame 'Table1' below that is missing the weightage column:

[Table1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l2QCe.png)

I have customers that e-visit my business via different channels and each customer is attributed to a channel based on the number visits per channel. So each channel gets a weighted score per customer (see Weightage column). I would like to create for loop that iterates across every row of my table. The weighted score per campaign is repeated per customer, so that by the end, the sum of all the weighted weighted scores would equal to the distinct number of customers (5).

Once I get this table (add the missing 'weightage' column to my current table), I would like to create a new DataFrame (see [Table2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K6r3s.png)) that shows the percentage weightage of each distinct channel. To create this table, I need to find the sum of all the weighted scores of each channel in 'Table1'...again, this should sum up to (5). And then I would divide each channel's sum of weighted scores by the total number of distinct customers (5) to get the weightage percentage.

Essentially, I need help building a script to add a weightage column to my Table1, and then a script to create Table2.

I'm still in the process of learning Pandas, so any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: (1) please your tables as text, not screenshot (2) please include a worked example of how  you calculate the final output

Answer (score 0):

Considering the lack of a reproducible example, I'll assume you have a pandas dataframe called `df`.

In order to perform the desired operations, you should use `groupby`.

First use a group by `Customer ID` to create Table 1:

```
table1 = df.assign(Weightage = lambda df_: 
    df_['Visits']/df_.groupby('Customer ID')['Visits'].transform(sum))
```

Then, you group by `Channel`

```
table2 = table1 \
    .groupby('Channel', as_index=False, sort=False)[['Weightage']].sum() \
    .assign(Percentage = lambda df_: df_['Weightage']/df_['Weightage'].sum()) \
    .assign(Percentage = lambda df_: df_['Percentage'].apply('{:.0%}'.format))
```

The last apply just return the result in a string format (with %) according to Table2. If you want it as a numeric, just remove it.